# n where it gives certain remainder for certain number

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility, gre-exam

I am studying for GRE and need help with following question

> When the positive integer n is divided by 3, the remainder is 2 and when n is divided by 5, the remainder is 1. What is the least possible value of n?

Answer says 11, but gives no explanation.

I tried to solve this, i.e.

$n = 3x + 2$

$n = 5y + 1$

$3x + 2 = 5y + 1$

$3x - 5y + 1 = 0$

$1 = 5y - 3x$

I'm not sure how to proceed. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the two congruences $n\equiv_3 2$ and $n\equiv_5 1$. We know that the answer should look like $5k+1$ for some integer $k$, and we see that if $k=0$, we get $1$, when $k=1$ we get $6$, and when $k=2$ we get $11$. In trying $1$ and $6$ we see that it doesn't work. But it does for $11$.

Comment: So you are plugging in values for $k$ in $5k + 1$ till you get $11$? But what about $3x + 2$?

Comment: $11$ is the first value that satisfies both congruences, which is what we are looking for.

Comment: In other words, we simply plug in numbers. For $n=1$ we divide by $3$ and see if remainder is $2$. For $n=6$, we divide by $3$ and see if remainder is $2$, etc?

Comment: Plug in numbers that satisfy one of the congruences, and see if it satisfies the other.

Comment: Since we're dealing with mod 5 and 3 there are a limited number of answers.

Comment: Thank you .... I guess they don't call it "Quantitative Reasoning" exam for nothing!

Comment: Anytime. Good luck on your exam!